# Azure AD Sign In Page without Domain Name

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Has anyone found a way to use the Azure AD sign in page without the domain name?

For example, oscar instead of oscar@tenant.onmicrosoft.com.

I already am aware of using the *"login_hint"* parameter; however, I'd like to the user to not see the "@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" at all.  I think it would lead to confusion.

Also, I want to avoid creating a custom page & having access to the username/password by using the *UserCredential* type and *AcquireToken* method.  See [this](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/) for reasons.

The domain name (@tenant.onmicrosoft.com) is going to be a deal breaker for my employer.  They don't want to see it and I can understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no way to avoid using of `@domain` with the login at Azure AD.

However, you are not forced to use `@tenant.onmicrsoft.com` - you can freely [configure your own domain](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2014/03/24/configuring-a-custom-domain-name-for-a-microsoft-azure-web-sites.aspx) and have users login with `@mycompany.com`. You have to make your employer think in 21st century, not in middle ages of early Internet access.

Comment: Understood.  I didn't use our domain in the problem because I didn't think that would affect the solution to the problem.  (I believe it does affect if you want the customization images to appear.)

Its the "@mycompany.com" that I'm trying to avoid. Kind of like when you log into so many websites, you only use a username and password.

Comment: but this creates so huge frustration when new user comes and "astaykov" is already taken ... then I have to choose among fancy new names. While e-mail uniquely identifies an Internet User and there is no chance (beside malicious attack) another user to want to register with same e-mail.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding how this is used because I didn't think it was an email at all.  It is simply a username that is associated with your Azure AD and thus it is username@mycompany.com.  You still have the same frustration that it is already taken whether it is username only or username@mycompany.com.

Comment: No, because mycompany.com will only ever be in a single directory (which is typically one organization, where such clashes are minimal, if not non-existant). It makes more sense when you consider the additional services that use Azure AD, such as Office 365 (at which point it *is* and email address).

Comment: I think it is a problem with their implementation, but as you said from the beginning, there is "no way to avoid" it.  After talking to a MS Support Engineer, that is confirmed.  Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a `problem` though ... I personally don't see any issue with that. Even when I create sites and require (the stupid) registration with local username/password, I enforce using a whole e-mail as username.

Comment: @astaykov, but what is the user feeling with that. Is it important for you what he feels when you say "I cannot give you a username as you know until today, because your user may collide with other users that doesn't belong to your domain"?